# d3.js or browser setting opacity to 0 when switching tabs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dynamic bar chart I created using d3.js. By dynamic I mean that both the height and number of bars is constantly changing. The problem I'm running into is that when I switch to another tab in my browser and then switch back, occasionally one or more of the bars has it's style attribute set to `opacity: 0`.

I've attached a picture showing the problem. Additionally, I see the same effect at http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/5372077 if I click update very fast.

[image]

What is causing this behavior?

Edit: Should add a relevant piece of the code:

```
    bars.exit().transition().style({opacity: 0}).remove();
```

I'm using Firefox 17.0.10 on Scientific Linux 6.4.

Comment: It sounds like this is caused by some kind of race condition/interrupted transition. Does it work correctly if you remove the transition?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, yes it does. Although the exiting bars do not look very nice, as they block the view of incoming bars.

Comment: Looks like the root cause is basically that several interfering transitions are started. The only real solution for this would be to use the new 3.3 API that allows you to interrupt running transitions -- see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1410